# javascript slideToogle not hiding when another is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, slidetoggle

I have 3 click events

A B C.

When i click A, A shows "aaaaa"

When i click B, B shows "Bbbbbbbbb"

When i click C, C shows "Cccccccc"

Problem is when i click A, and then B, A still shows.

What i want is A to automatically hide when B or C is clicked.

At the moment if i click all 3 (a,b,c) it will show them all. but i want it to show one by one only.

This is my code:

Javascript

```
 $(function () {
          $('.expandContent3 span').click(function () {
              $('.showMe3').slideToggle('slow');
          });
      });
      $(function () {
          $('.expandContent1 span').click(function () {
              $('.showMe1').slideToggle('slow');
          });
      });
      $(function () {
          $('.expandContent2 span').click(function () {
              $('.showMe2').slideToggle('slow');
          });
```

HTML CODE:

```
  <div class="readMore1 expandContent1" style="cursor: pointer;float: left;margin-right: 8px;">
<span><b>A</b></span></div>
<div class="readMore2 expandContent2" style="cursor: pointer;float: left;margin-right: 8px;">
<span><b>B</b></span></div>
   <div class="readMore3 expandContent3" style="cursor: pointer;float: left;margin-right: 8px;">
<span><b>C</b></span></div>

 <div class="showMe1" style="display:none; clear:both;">
<p><b>aaaaaaa</b></p>
<p><b>aaaaaaa</b></p>
 </div>

 <div class="showMe2" style="display:none; clear:both;">
<p><b>Bbbbbbbbb</b></p>
<p><b>Bbbbbbbbb</b></p>
</div>

<div class="showMe3" style="display:none; clear:both;">
<p><b>Cccccccc</b></p>
<p><b>Ccccccc</b></p>
 </div>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add checks to all your click handlers:

```
$('.expandContent1 span').click(function () {
    $('.showMe1').slideToggle('slow');
    if( $('.showMe2').is( ':visible' ) ) $('.showMe2').slideUp('slow');
    if( $('.showMe3').is( ':visible' ) ) $('.showMe3').slideUp('slow');
});
```

etc

**EDIT**

If you will have many of this stuff you can achieve "accordion" functionality for example by changing all class names from `readMore[n]` to just `readMore`, same is for `showMe[n]` to `showMe`. And change your JS to:

```
$(function () {
  $('.readMore').click(function () {
    $('.showMe').slideUp('slow');
    $('.showMe').eq( $( this ).index() ).slideDown('slow');
  });
});
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qk5vR/).

Don't forget to keep your `readMore` and `showMe` blocks order in layout.

Comment: that works,, but once i do it for a-z the code is going to be very long. i wil have to use expandContent1 to expanadconte26, with all the if statements. i just have 3 expandContent as its already to much. no way to trim the code..

Comment: thanks, works. however look at the update i added, works better for me this.

Comment: @al123 better add your update to original question or add your own answer. Cheers ;)